# Savon appends "Input" to the operation that I'm calling

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon, cucm

I've been tasked with writing some checks around a soap api, and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I've imported the wsdl into SoapUI to test with. SoapUI parsed out the wsdl and generated a sample request for the operation I want to call (PerfmonOpenSession). [Here's a sample of what it generated](http://dpaste.com/1388110/).. when I submitted the request, it came back successful.

When I try to do the same thing with Savon in Ruby, [it returns this](http://dpaste.com/1388089/plain/). I noticed that savon is using the tns namespace, and also appends the word "Input" to the operation name. So rather than calling soap:PermonOpenSession, I'm calling tns:PerfmonOpenSessionInput (which doesn't exist).

I'm even further confused by the fact that the wsdl actually defines an "Input" message for the port [(seen here](http://dpaste.com/1388120/) at line 224). So.. is Savon doing the right thing here? If so, how does SoapUI know how to properly form the soap request? How do I make savon's request look like the one that SoapUI generates?

Answer (score 0):

I cases like this I usually skip the WSDL and create a client without it. That works with Savon v1 and v2. You have to set

```
endpoint
```

and

```
namespace
```

You might also want to set

```
soap_action
```

explicitely. The documentation at http://savonrb.com explains what to do. In case you need further help let us know.